# Haskell: how do you check runtime types on IO?

Tags: haskell, io, typechecking

I'm making my way through some introductory material on Haskell and trying to complete this silly Rock, Paper, Scissors implementation for the command line.

I would think that a type guard on the input would be good enough to convince the compiler that the input is of the type `RPS`, but alas, it is not.

How does one go about telling the compiler that input data is of one type or another?

```hs
data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors

_shoot :: RPS -> RPS -> String
_shoot Rock Paper = "Paper beats rock, you win!"
_shoot Paper Rock = "Paper beats rock, you loose."
_shoot Rock Scissors = "Rock beats scissors, you loose."
_shoot Scissors Rock = "Rock beats scissors, you win!"
_shoot Paper Scissors = "Scissors beats paper, you win!"
_shoot Scissors Paper = "Scissors beats paper, you loose!"
_shoot Rock Rock = "Tie!"
_shoot Scissors Scissors = "Tie!"
_shoot Paper Paper = "Tie!"

isRPS :: String -> Bool
isRPS s = elem s ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"
  choice <- getLine
  if isRPS choice -- this was my idea but is apparently not good enough
    then putStrLn (_shoot choice Rock) 
--                        ^^^^^^
-- Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘RPS’ Expected type: RPS Actual type: String
    else putStrLn "Invalid choice."
```

Comment: This is a common instance of "boolean blindness", i.e. reducing the information you know to a boolean even when you have more information at hand. `isRPS` returns a boolean (carrying true or false) instead of a more informative type (carrying the RPS value or an error). In this case `Maybe RPS` suffices. Sometimes you want `Either SomeError RPS`, if you have multiple errors to return. `Bool` is not used so frequently in Haskell as in some other languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not transform the `choice` (which is a `String`) to an `RPS`, or even better a `Maybe RPS`:

```
readRPS :: String -> Maybe RPS
readRPS "rock" = Just Rock
readRPS "paper" = Just Paper
readRPS "scissors" = Just Scissors
readRPS _ = Nothing
```

Here we thus return a `Just x` given the input is valid (with `x` the corresponding `RPS` item), or `Nothing` if the string is not a valid option.

We can then implement this as:

```
import Data.Char(toLower)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"
    choice <- getLine
    case readRPS (map toLower choice) of
        Just rps -> putStrLn (_shoot rps Rock) 
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid choice."
    main
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect use case for Maybe - I should have seen that. I just noticed that rps and Rock need to switched for the game to work right.

Answer (score 4):

You're nearly there, you just need the [read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) function to convert the user's string to your `RPS` data type.

The first thing you need to do is to make `RPS` an instance of the `Read` typeclass. This can be done easily by amending your `data` declaration to:

```
data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors deriving Read
```

what `deriving Read` does is give `RPS` a default instance of the `Read` typeclass, which works in the obvious way: `read "Rock"` will become `Rock` and so on, provided the compiler knows you're using `read` in a context where a value of type `RPS` is expected.

Then all you need to do, in your `main` function, is change this:

```
putStrLn (_shoot choice Rock)
```

to

```
putStrLn (_shoot (read choice) Rock)
```

Since `_shoot` has a type signature telling GHC that its first argument must be an `RPS` value, it will know to use the instance of `read` defined for your `RPS` type, and all should be well, since you've already restricted the valid user choices to those 3 specific strings.

(Note that for larger programs there are safer and better ways of handling things like this - see Willem's answer for one simple approach - but this is fine for a basic learning exercise.)

Comment: Thanks, using the Maybe type seems to make more sense to me, but it’s nice to know that there are different ways to do things.